# sleep-free kernel functions

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt, atomic

I wonder if there exists any reference material (tables or some sort) detailing every Linux kernel functions that are schedule-free (sleep free) to be used safely under atomic or interrupt context

It would be good to check things out while doing coding

Comment: I think Stackoverflow isn't the right place to ask for documentation. I wonder why G...e doesn't show you hits.

Comment: Some of functions are instrumented with `might_sleep*()` macros.